# Adding validation to gridview with autogenerated columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can you add input validation to Gridview if you are using autogenerated columns? I have a list with car objects in it. The gridview is bound to the list. The gridview has adding and editing functionality. And I would have to validate the fields like registration plate. How can I do that using validation control?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about adding validation controls such as a `CompareValidator` to the GridView whilst it's in edit mode, you can programmatically add validator controls using your GridView's RowDataBound event:

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"...
```

**C#**

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (gv.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox; // get reference to your Control to validate (you specify cell and control indeces)
            tb.ID = "reg_" + e.Row.RowIndex; // give your Control to validate an ID

            CompareValidator cv = new CompareValidator(); // Create validator and configure
            cv.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.GreaterThan;
            cv.Type = ValidationDataType.Double;
            cv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            cv.ErrorMessage = "<br/>Not a valid number";
            cv.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            cv.ControlToValidate = tb.ID;
            e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(cv); // Add validator to GridView cell
        }
    }
}
```

On the row that you're editing, you can reference the control you want to link the validator to, e.g. your car registration `TextBox`. Then you need to give it an ID, create a validator and specify its `ControlToValidate` propery as the `TextBox` ID, and then add the validator to the same cell that contains your `TextBox`.

This example shows forcing a `TextBox` to only allow Doubles.